# What motherboard can support dual RTX 4090 GPUs?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, computer-building, hardware-rec, overclocking

I am trying to build a deep learning PC using the following parts:

- 2x MSI Suprim X RTX 4090 graphic card
- 1x Intel core i9 14900K CPU
- 4x 48GB DDR5 RAM (most likely G.Skill or Corsair @ 5600MT~6000MT)
- 2x 2TB Samsung 990 Pro SSD
- 1x 1650W Thermaltake PSU

The only parts I am struggling with is the motherboard and case. I don't know what motherboard won't reduce the performance of dual 4090 cards and also provides enough space for the airflow?

I am also thinking about using 2x Suprim x liquid cooling cards or 1 air and 1 liquid cooled card. But I am not sure if liquid cooled cards can last as same as air cooled cards in long term under 24/7 workload?

Please help me to find the best motherboard for my setup? ***(I should choose either between MSI suprim x or Suprim x liquid because I know a guy selling those cards in a good price)***

EDIT: Regarding a question in comments, I came up with the following setup finally:

- Case: Thermaltake CTE C750 ARGB (I wasn't able to close the glass door for Lian Li O11 EVO XL case)
- GPU: 2x MSI Suprim X Liquid (You can also use one liquid and one non liquid graphics card)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
- CPU cooler: Arctic liquid Freezer 2 420mm radiator AIO
- RAM: Corsair DDR5 5200Mhz 192GB kit (4x48GB) (I think it's a bit overkil and you can go with a 2x48GB kit, then add another kit if it's needed)
- PSU: Be Quiet dark power pro 13 1600W titanium
- Motherboard: Asus ProArt X670E (You should update the BIOS to be able to detect 4 RAM dims @ 4800Mhz)
- Storage: 2x 2TB Samsung 990 Pro NVME (I guess I would buy a Seagate 22TB HDD as well)
- Cooling Fans: I used 7x 140mm Thermaltake CT140 fans as intake(3 came with the case)(I also tried Arctic P14 140mm fans but they were too loud compare to Thermaltake CT140 fans). The CPU cooler radiator and gpu radiator fans act as 7 exhaust fans.

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: Nvidia stopped actively supporting SLI years ago. There is [NVLINk](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/nvlink-bridges/) but it doesn’t support 4080s or consumer GPUs. Hardware recommendations are out of scope

Comment: The MSI Supreme X RTX 4090 appears to be a 4-slot GPU. Most consumer motherboards, including larger E-ATX motherboards, won't provide the appopriate spacing, and chassis selection will also be a challenge (even very large tower chassis are unlikely to provide 8-9 slots needed - consider that most motherboards don't have a PCIe slot in the first position on the chassis). The Suprim X Liquid would be a better choice, but you'll want at least 1 slot between GPUs to accomodate airflow to the fan on the Liquid.

Comment: Could you share what setup you finally purchased? RAM, motherboard, cooling system for the GPUs, and case. I also want to mount 2x4090 and I'm having the same doubts you had. Thanks!

Comment: @Kikolo: I added my setup to the EDIT part.

Comment: @best_of_man that's very helpful, thanks! Are you happy overall with the performance of your machine? Would you change anything, apart from what you commented about RAM?

Comment: @Kikolo: If this setup looks so expensive to you, you can replace 2x 4090 with 2x 3090. This way you can save $2000~$2500. But you must also use Asus Crosshare or ASRock taichi EATX motherboards because you need more space between PCIE slots (3090 cards are thicker than 4090 liquid cards).

Answer (score 5):

The motherboard won't really reduce the performance of your GPUs if both PCI-E ports are x16 Gen4. This is what the RTX 4090 is meant for. Some of the motherboards sold today have even newer PCI-E Gen5 ports which makes them future-proof.

If you're interested, here's an [article](https://www.techpowerup.com/review/nvidia-geforce-rtx-4090-pci-express-scaling/28.html) on the impact that PCI-E might have on a RTX 4090 performance.

Space for the airflow would be dependent on the distance between the 2 PCI-E ports that you would use. I suggest to get an ATX (not micro ATX) motherboard model which would be bigger and would potentially have more spacing between PCI-E x16 ports.

Some motherboards supporting Intel Gen14 might require a BIOS update before using these processors, so you should preferably get a model that has an USB port letting you update the BIOS even without powering on the PC. This is just in case the BIOS version installed in the factory is not Intel Gen14 ready.

Regarding the GPU cooling, if you go the liquid cooled cards route be sure to have enough place in your case in order to install the radiators (there are 240mm each it would seem).

Liquid coolers might allow you to have lower temperatures and/or have a more silent setup, so there are in theory superior to air coolers and would extend the GPUs' life.

Air coolers on the other hand would be safer as you won't have any water running in your system. I'm always advising not to install liquid cooling if the person do not understand the risks involved and the fact that a leak might appear after some use (months, years) and if it goes undetected it can possibly ruin your components - GPU, PSU, etc.

Hope this helps !

P.S : I would suggest to see what is the max frequency that the motherboard supports before spending money on RAM

Comment: Thank you for your advice, specially about leaking of liquid cooling system. This is one of the RAM options I was talking about in my question: https://www.amazon.com/CORSAIR-VENGEANCE-5600MHz-Compatible-Computer/dp/B0BVN19N31/ref=sr_1_3?crid=17LG50J29MF4E&keywords=96gb+ram&qid=1700358765&sprefix=96gb+ram%2Caps%2C152&sr=8-3

Comment: You're absolutely right about the RAM, this is something very new I was not aware of with DDR5 :)